# Python adding elements to list of set updates all sets in list

Tags: python, list, object, set

I have a Graph object with an attribute adj_list, which is initialized to a list of empty sets. When I call my addEdge(self, u, v) function, the expected behavior is that u gets added to the set at adj_list[v] and v gets added to the set at adj_list[u], but after printing out what gets added in the console, it seems that calling self.adj_list[u].add(v) adds v to every single set in the list.

Here's my constructor:

```
def __init__(self, n):
        """
        Constructor
        ------------
        Parameters:
        n: int
            number of nodes in the graph
        ------------
        Attribute:
        adj_list: list of int lists
        int list at index i contains the neighbors of node i (nodes represented as ints 
        from 0 to n-1)
        """
        # adjacency list of graph (entry at index i = list of neighbors of node i) 
        initialized with empty neighbor lists
        self.adj_list = [set()] * n
```

And here's the add_edge function:

```
def addEdge(self, u, v):
        """
        Adds an edge between vertices u & v
        -----------
        Parameters:
        u: int
            vertex at one end of edge
        v: int
            vertex at another end of edge
        -----------
        Returns:
        void
        """
        if u < 0 or u > len(self.adj_list) - 1 or v < 0 or v > len(self.adj_list) - 1:
            raise Exception("Invalid start/end vertices for edge")

        # add edge by adding to list of neighbors if it's not already in
        if v not in self.adj_list[u] and u not in self.adj_list[v]:
            # undirected graph -> add edge in both directions
            print("before", self.adj_list)
            self.adj_list[u].add(v)
            print("one add", self.adj_list)
            self.adj_list[v].add(u)
            print("after", self.adj_list)
```

This is how I called the function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Graph(3)
    g.addEdge(0, 1)
```

This is what printed out:

```
before [set(), set(), set()]
one add [{1}, {1}, {1}]
after [{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}]
```

Could anyone help me figure out why this is happening and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: This is because you are having three references to set and not three sets itself because of `[set()] * n`.

Comment: Try comparing the different elements in the list to each other with the 'is' operator. e.g. adj_list[0] is adj_list[1]   >   and if that returns True, then youre just creating multiple references to the same object, hence they all update at the same time by editing one of them.

Comment: I closed as a duplicate - I understand that you have a list of sets rather than a list of lists, but the underlying problem is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.adj_list = [set()] * n` creates 3 references to the same set.  Use `self.adj_list = [set() for _ in range(3)]` to create three different sets.